# Jsoup fails to parse elements on very rare occasion

Tags: java, xml, rss, jsoup

I've migrated the RSS parsing in my application from [rome](/questions/tagged/rome) to [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup) recently and when trying to parse files from a source, Jsoup will fail to parse `<` and `>` correctly, leading to `&lt;` and `&gt;` in the retrieved `Document`, further leading to issues when trying to use `Document::select`.

### MCVE

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;

public class MCVE {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        Jsoup.connect("https://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/files/page18")
             .parser(Parser.xmlParser())
             .get()
             .select("item")
             .stream()
             .map(e -> e.select("pubDate"))
             .flatMap(Collection::stream)
             .map(Element::text)
             .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The above code will currently (The RSS feed is constantly updating, and the problem doesn't occur from local files) print the following:

```
Wed, 22 Nov 2017 15:29:54 GMT
Wed, 22 Nov 2017 15:29:43 GMT
Wed, 22 Nov 2017 15:29:36 GMT
Wed, 22 Nov 2017 15:29:28 GMT
Wed, 22 Nov 2017 15:29:22 GMT
Wed, 22 Nov 2017 15:27:23 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 23:23:23 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:21:38 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:20:12 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:18:15 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:16:17 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:14:37 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:13:34 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:11:33 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:07:49 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:06:56 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:04:19 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:03:57 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 10:11:11 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 04:54:00 GMT
Tue, 21 Nov 2017 04:04:00 GMT</pubDate> Ubuntu Security Notice 3483-2 - USN-3483-1 fixed a vulnerability in procmail. This update provides the corresponding update for Ubuntu 12.04 ESM. Jakub Wilk discovered that the formail tool incorrectly handled certain malformed mail messages. An attacker could use this flaw to cause formail to crash, resulting in a denial of service, or possibly execute arbitrary code. Various other issues were also addressed.
Mon, 20 Nov 2017 22:22:00 GMT
Mon, 20 Nov 2017 16:16:00 GMT
Mon, 20 Nov 2017 16:15:00 GMT
Mon, 20 Nov 2017 16:14:00 GMT
```

This is a snippet from the `Document` returned to me by Jsoup.

```
<item> 
 <title>Ubuntu Security Notice USN-3483-2</title> 
 <link>
  https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/145055/USN-3483-2.txt
 </link> 
 <guid isPermaLink="true">
  https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/145055/USN-3483-2.txt
 </guid> 
 <comments>
  https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/145055/Ubuntu-Security-Notice-USN-3483-2.html
 </comments> 
 <pubDate>
  Tue, 21 Nov 2017 04:04:00 GMT&lt;/pubDate&gt; <!-- the affected line -->
  <description>
   Ubuntu Security Notice 3483-2 - USN-3483-1 fixed a vulnerability in procmail. This update provides the corresponding update for Ubuntu 12.04 ESM. Jakub Wilk discovered that the formail tool incorrectly handled certain malformed mail messages. An attacker could use this flaw to cause formail to crash, resulting in a denial of service, or possibly execute arbitrary code. Various other issues were also addressed.
  </description> 
  <category></category> 
 </pubDate>
</item>
```

Here, some of the characters have been parsed wrongly while the xml on the website is well formed.

---

When using the same URL with a trailing slash (`https://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/files/page18/`), the problem does not occur on the same page, however it will occur on different pages instead.

The pages of the feed on which the problem will occur will also change due to the active nature of the feed. If the problem fails to occur on page 18, I will update with a new page. It will also not occur if the file is downloaded separately and then parsed with `Jsoup::parse`.

The Jsoup version is **1.11.2**.

### Additional MCVE

This MCVE shows that the problem occurs only when Parsing the response with Jsoup, the actual downloaded XML is fine:

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MCVE {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/files/page18").execute();

        // Well formed XML
        System.out.println(response.body());

        // Malformed XML
        System.out.println(response.parse());
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a problem with malformed XML that the site generates? Garbage in, garbage out?

Comment: *"The item where the problem occurs"* Is this the raw XML you're trying to parse? If so, it's just wrong. So, that's what you need to fix. If not, what **is** the raw XML?

Comment: @SurfMan The site seems fine when inspecting in the browser, and as I said, when downloading the file and using `Jsoup::parse`, the file works just fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry, I should have been more clear with that and I will edit: This is from the `Document` that is given back to me by `Jsoup.connect[...].get()`, the raw `xml` is well formed.

Comment: I'm frankly having a hard time believing that if the XML is well-formed, Jsoup is introducing a problem with it. Obviously it *could* be true, bugs happen, but as the Pragmatic Programmer tells us, "`select` isn't broken." To believe that, I'd have to see it: An example of the actual XML, which when passed to Jsoup, fails. I think you'll need to separate out the two bits: Downloading it, and parsing it, in the code, and download it another way. That's also going to be useful debugging.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Feel free to run the MCVE and validate the provided xml file separately. I've validated and it came out with no errors. Also when I used Rometools previously, it didn't show the same errors. When downloading the file to a `Connection.Response` object, the body is still intact (When printing out with `Connection.Response::body`). The error gets introduced only when parsing with Jsoup. I'll provide a seperate MCVE.

Comment: @Marv: There's no MCVE in the question. There's an example of an invalid XML document, which Jsoup quite correctly doesn't parse. That's not an MCVE of the problem you're describing. Or rather, if it is, as I said above, the problem is the XML, not Jsoup.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please [visit the page](https://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/files/page18) and validate the xml. It is well formed. I'm not quite sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @Marv Indeed, it has the same behaviour here, on the same item at 04:04:00. I have tested the URL with `new URL(...).openConnection()` and reading the InputStream, but it consistently returns correct XML. As a workaround you could call `setTrackErrors(100)` on the Parser and if the `parser.getErrors()` is not empty, try the page again. Curious case, this.

Comment: @SurfMan: What do you see **on the wire**? `</pubDate>` or `&lt;/pubDate&gt;`?

Comment: @Marv: What version of Jsoup are you using?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When I run `curl -s --get https://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/files/page18 | grep "pubDate"` I get consistenly no errors: only `</pubDate>`. I would say that's as "on the wire" as it gets.

Comment: @SurfMan: Well, no, as "on the wire" as it gets would be wireshark or something, but one can go too far. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 1.11.2 (Latest)

Comment: @Marv: When I do `java -cp .:jsoup-1.11.2.jar Mcve | grep "&lt;/pubDate&gt;"` with that MCVE.java (I had to rename it Mcve.java, javac didn't like it in all caps), I consistently get no output -- e.g., the incorrectly-encoded < and > aren't there. Something like 30 runs now. (I did modify it to output that string once, just to check the test.) This is on \*nix. In case it helps.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried Wireshark, but it's HTTPS. I can show you the encrypted handshake if you like :)

Comment: This appears to be an actual bug in [tag:jsoup], see https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection::get` and `org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.Response::parse`, [here's my corresponding github issue](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/995) and [here's a repo](https://github.com/marvk/JsoupParseBug) replicating the bug.

[This will be fixed in `Jsoup` 1.11.3](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/995#issuecomment-353760156)